# Does using a JDBC driver in a Java program work without reflection?

Tags: java, jdbc, dynamic-loading

Is it correct that when we  dynamically load a .class class file, we    need to use reflection to access the methods defined in the class?

When we use a JDBC driver in our Java program,

- if I  am correct, the JDBC driver is also dynamically loaded behind the scene.
- But we never need to use reflection to access the methods defined in the JDBC driver. Instead we `import java.sql` and access the classes and methods defined in the `java.sql`.

Under the hood, is there reflection undergoing? If not, how does it work without reflection?

In general, when we dynamically load a .java class file, how can we eliminate or hide the use of reflection to access the methods defined in the class, just like a JDBC driver?

By the way, does a JDBC driver define exactly a class?

Thanks.

Comment: Carefully look at the `java.sql` package. Almost everything is an ***interface*** not a class, so any class implementing the interface can be plugged in behind the scenes.

Comment: *FYI:* You cannot "dynamically load a .java class file". You load `.class` files, not `.java` files.

Comment: @Andreas  Thanks. corrected.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC driver needs to implement [`java.sql.Driver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) interface (e.g. [`oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`](https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)). Apart from that the JDBC driver code is just plain Java code. It can use reflection or any other Java language feature. It's up to the driver vendor to decide if it's worth it e.g. using classes introduced in Java 8 will make it compatible only with Java 8+.

What is and isn't dynamically loaded depends on the JVM and the implementation of `ClassLoader`. Certain technologies like OSGI give more flexibility by implementing a `ClassLoader` that allows for unloading parts of the application.

Loading the JDBC driver class should happen so infrequently, and be cached by JVM, that cost of this one reflective call to load the driver should be negligible. A single `SELECT 1` query will be orders of magnitude more expensive than loading the driver bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with JDBC 4.0 it is no longer necessary to do any reflection-related calls to work with JDBC drivers, as any driver discovered on your class path is loaded automatically.

If your code must support pre-JDBC 4 code, or if your JDBC driver is *not* located on your class path, you must call `Class.forName` to load the driver.

> Under the hood, is there reflection undergoing?

JDBC 4.0 uses [Service Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) mechanism to locate JDBC drivers without doing reflection directly. At some point, however, JDBC driver class needs to be loaded, so a reflection call must be performed.

Comment: Thanks. In general, when we dynamically load a .java class file, how can we eliminate or hide the use of reflection to access the methods defined in the class, just like a JDBC driver?

Comment: SPI is still using reflection, just in a contained and pre-debugged library.

Comment: @Ben: Make the loaded class implement well-known interfaces, just like JDBC drivers do. The reflection is only needed for the actual loading operation; then it's just like any other loaded Java class.

Comment: @chrylis  Thanks. Could you point me some links to some example code?

Comment: @Ben: JDBC itself. Look at the JDBC interfaces you're using (in `javax.sql`) and drivers for various databases. The JDBC drivers for Postgres and MySQL are open-source, so you can inspect the code directly.